# Return table records based on user role / table Join failing - linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I am building a MVC 5 (EF6) application that has a photographer table that's linked to the users table.

I identify a photographer by setting a role on the user account.  The photographer table holds additional information not table. I have different types of users accessing the system.

I need to get the photographer table records based on the user being in the photographer role. I have the following solution but it comes back with the following error message when i try to access query result.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
var photogpraherRole = db.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == "photographer");
var users = photogpraherRole.Users.ToList();

var photographersList =
    from photographer in db.Photographers
    join user in users on photographer.User.Id equals user.UserId
    orderby photographer.Priority
    select photographer;

foreach (var photographer in photographersList)
{
    var photographerName = photographer.User.FirstName;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your 2nd line is the problem.Try using `var users= db.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.Name == "photographer")).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks @Shawn Yan.  This wasn't the full solution.   But i pointed me in the right direction.  I have posted the complete solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and the help from @Shawn Yan, this is the solution i came up with.

```
var photographerRole = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "photographer");
var disabledRole = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "disabled");

var users = db.Users.Where(m => m.Roles.All(r => r.RoleId == photographerRole.Id && r.RoleId != disabledRole.Id)).ToList();

var photographersList =
    from photographer in db.Photographers.ToList()
    join user in users on photographer.User.Id equals user.Id
    where photographer.Location == booking.location.Location
    orderby photographer.Priority
    select photographer;
var photographers = photographersList.ToList();
```